# Java: extending a class and implementing an interface that have the same method

Tags: java, syntax, specifications

Probably the following cannot be done (I am getting a compilation error: "The inherited method A.doSomthing(int) cannot hide the public abstract method in B"):

```
public class A {
    int doSomthing(int x) {
        return x;
    }
}

public interface B {
    int doSomthing(int x);
}

public class C extends A implements B {

    //trying to override doSomthing...

    int doSomthing(int x) {
        return doSomthingElse(x);
    }
}
```

Assuming I am allowed to change neither A nor B, my question is can I somehow define C in such a way that it will inherit from both A and B (suppose that it is required for some framework that C will be both an instance of A and B).

Or if not, how would you work around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please report your error. There's nothing obviously wrong here, except perhaps a missing @Overrides if you are using 1.6.

Comment: @bmargulies, there is no `public` and override is just an optional annoyance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

make the method public

```
public class C extends A implements B {

    //trying to override doSomthing...

    public int myMethod(int x) {
        return doSomthingElse(x);
    }
}
```

interface methods are always `public`

or just use composition instead of inheritance

Comment: Is it possible for a variable to both be a class instance and inherit an interface? In your example it would be something like `new C() implements X` assuming X is the interface

Comment: @Vadorequest implementing or extending is done at the class level not the instance level. To also implement X you need to add it to the interface list: `public class C extends A implements B, X{...}`

Answer (score 8):

The method `doSomethis()` is **package-private** in class A:

```
public class A {
    int doSomthing(int x) { // this is package-private
        return x;
    }
}
```

But it is **public** in the interface B:

```
public interface B {
    int doSomthing(int x); // this here is public by default
}
```

Compiler is taking the `doSomething()` inherited by C from A which is *package-private* as the implementation of the one in B which is *public*. That's why it's complaining -

> "The inherited method A.doSomthing(int) cannot hide the public abstract method in B"

Because, while *overriding* a method you can not narrow down the *access level* of the method.

Solution is easy, in class C -

```
@Override
public int doSomthing(int x) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with visibility.  You are using `default` (no modifier) visibility in `C` for `myMethod` but it needs to be `public` according to the interface `B`.

Now you might think you used the `default` visibility for all of them, since in neither `A`, `B`, nor `C` did you explicitly select one of `public`, `private`, or `protected`.  However, the interface uses `public` whether or not you explicitly indicate so.

Answer (score 0):

Simply making the method `public` when overriding it in `C` will do.