# Implementing an interface and extending a class having same method

Tags: java, interface

Small doubt with interface implementation and extending class.
This is my code.

```
public class intercheck extends inter implements in {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    intercheck a = new intercheck();
    a.show();
  }
}

class inter {
  public void show() {
    System.out.println("Class Show");
 }
}

interface in {
  public void show() {
    System.out.println("Interface show");
  }
}
```

I ran this code and got to know that class inter show() method ll be displayed.

Want to know the logic beyond this..

Comment: How about to read something about OOP basics?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: extending a class and implementing an interface that have the same method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761282/java-extending-a-class-and-implementing-an-interface-that-have-the-same-method)

Comment: The default implementation in the interface is there to be used if no other implementation is available. An implementation in a class takes priority.

Comment: @Vadim experienced Java developers may think this is a basic OOP principle, but in fact it's Java-specific. For example, C# behaves differently with code similar to this. And Python (the language the OP seems to be most familiar with) is *very* different - it has no interfaces, just abstract base classes.

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare not a duplicate. The other Q overrides the method in the derived class, but this Q is specifically about the case where it doesn't override it.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException OK "read something about OOP basics in Java" as long as question about Java and not Python, nor C#

Answer (score 1):

When you implemented `show()` in superclass and extended the class with it, the class inherited `show()` from the superclass, thereby implementing what was requested of it by the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
interface in {
   default void show() {
     System.out.println("Interface show");
   }
}
```

will be executed when, and only when implementing class does not have implementation of 
   `show()` (default was introduced only from Java 8 - before methods declared in interface could not have body at all).

`class intercheck` has it implemented in its parent class `inter`, so ...

```
class inter {
  public void show() {
     System.out.println("Class Show");
  }
}
```

executes. That's all logic behind this.

Answer (score 0):

> When you extend an interface that contains a default method, you can
>   do the following:
>
> **Not mention the default method at all, which lets your extended interface inherit the default method.**

With this from [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) You have inhereith the method from your `class inter`.  Even if is not set a default it will use your super class method.

And for conclude this you can read this

Interface Methods

> Default methods and abstract methods in interfaces are inherited like
>   instance methods.
>
> However, when the supertypes of a class or interface
>   provide multiple default methods with the same signature, the Java
>   compiler follows inheritance rules to resolve the name conflict.

From [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)